# Using relatedTo with a string of category ids

Tags: category, params, filtering

I have got a list of product variants being filtered by a string of category ids if there is some data in the category parameter with the following code:

(Note that I'm using the + character between category IDs, which getParam converts into spaces, so I'm splitting on spaces)

```
{% set categoryParams = craft.app.request.getParam('cat') %}
{% set categoryParamsArray = categoryParams|split(' ') %}

{% if categoryParams|length %}
    {% set results = craft.variants({product: product}).relatedTo(categoryParamsArray) %}
{% else %}
    {% set results = craft.variants({product: product}) %}
{% endif %}
```

This works perfectly if there is one category selected but no longer works when I select two or more. The responses are as follows:

✅No category selected: 22 results

✅One category selected: 5 results

❌Two categories selected: 22 results

Any advice on this method would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're checking for the length of `categoryParams`, but the name of the variable you're passing in is `categoryParamsArray`?

Comment: Left that bit out. Updated answer.